# Duplicados en tipos de conjuntos HashSet y LinkedHashSet en Java

Tags: java, set, collection

Estoy tratando de hacer un método estático "union" que devuelva la unión de dos conjuntos:

`static <E> Set<E> union(Set<E> conjunto1, Set<E> conjunto2)`

Al implementarlo tengo que utilizar uno de los tipos de conjuntos, pero solo funciona si utilizo TreeSet, si utilizo los otros tipos (HashSet o LinkedHashSet) el código devuelve un conjunto con duplicados, por ejemplo:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedHashSet<Cliente> conjuntoClientes = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        conjuntoClientes.add(new Cliente("666666R", "Ana", "1998-01-12"));
        Cliente cliente = new Cliente("123456X", "Antonio", "2001-08-15");
        conjuntoClientes.add(cliente);
        conjuntoClientes.add(new Cliente("555555Z", "Andres", "2005-05-23"));

        LinkedHashSet<Cliente> otrosClientes = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        otrosClientes.add(new Cliente("555555Z", "Andres", "2005-05-23"));
        otrosClientes.add(new Cliente("666666R", "Ana", "1998-01-12"));
        otrosClientes.add(new Cliente("999999T", "Rosa", "2003-09-18"));
    
        Set<Cliente> unionCli = union(conjuntoClientes, otrosClientes);
        System.out.println(unionCli);
    }

    static <E> Set<E> union(Set<E> conjunto1, Set<E> conjunto2){
        Set<E> resultado = new LinkedHashSet<>(conjunto1);
        resultado.addAll(conjunto2);
        return resultado;
    }
```

Me devuelve:

```
[dni=666666R, nombre=Ana, edad=25
, dni=123456X, nombre=Antonio, edad=21
, dni=555555Z, nombre=Andres, edad=17
, dni=555555Z, nombre=Andres, edad=17
, dni=666666R, nombre=Ana, edad=25
, dni=999999T, nombre=Rosa, edad=19
]
```

La clase Cliente es esta:

```
public class Cliente implements Comparable<Cliente> {
    String dni;
    String nombre;
    LocalDate fechaNacimiento;
    
    Cliente(String dni, String nombre, String fechaNacimiento){
        this.dni = dni;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.fechaNacimiento = LocalDate.parse(fechaNacimiento);
    }
    
    int edad() {
        return (int)fechaNacimiento.until(LocalDate.now(), ChronoUnit.YEARS);
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object ob) {
        return dni.equals(((Cliente)ob).dni);
    }
    
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Cliente otro) {
        return dni.compareTo(otro.dni);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "dni=" + dni + ", nombre=" + nombre + ", edad=" + edad() + "\n";
    }
}
```

Al implementar el método con TreeSet no ocurre:

```
static <E> Set<E> union(Set<E> conjunto1, Set<E> conjunto2){
    Set<E> resultado = new TreeSet<>(conjunto1);
    resultado.addAll(conjunto2);
    return resultado;
}
```

No sé si alguien me puede aclarar esta incongruencia.

Answer (score 2):

Debes asegurarte de que la clase Cliente implemente correctamente los métodos `hashCode()` y `equals()` para que `HashSet` pueda identificar y eliminar los elementos duplicados. Te muestro un ejemplo:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Probando {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Cliente> conjunto1 = new HashSet<>();
        conjunto1.add(new Cliente("12345678A", "Juan", 25));
        conjunto1.add(new Cliente("87654321B", "María", 30));
        conjunto1.add(new Cliente("98765432C", "Pedro", 20));

        Set<Cliente> conjunto2 = new HashSet<>();
        conjunto2.add(new Cliente("87654321B", "María", 30));
        conjunto2.add(new Cliente("45633211H", "Lucas", 22));
        conjunto2.add(new Cliente("70450521K", "Ana", 27));

        Set<Cliente> conjuntoUnido = union(conjunto1, conjunto2);

        System.out.println(conjunto1);
        System.out.println(conjunto2);
        System.out.println(conjuntoUnido);
    }
    public static <E> Set<E> union(Set<E> conjunto1, Set<E> conjunto2) {
        Set<E> conjuntoUnido = new HashSet<>();
        conjuntoUnido.addAll(conjunto1);
        conjuntoUnido.addAll(conjunto2);
        return conjuntoUnido;
    }
}
class Cliente {

    private final String dni;
    private final String nombre;
    private final int edad;

    public Cliente(String dni, String nombre, int edad) {
        this.dni = dni;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.edad = edad;
    }

    public String getDni() { return dni; }
    public String getNombre() { return nombre; }
    public int getEdad() { return edad; }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Cliente [dni=" + dni + ", nombre=" + nombre + ", edad=" + edad + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        Cliente other = (Cliente) obj;
        if (dni == null) {
            if (other.dni != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!dni.equals(other.dni)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (edad != other.edad) {
            return false;
        }
        if (nombre == null) {
            if (other.nombre != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!nombre.equals(other.nombre)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int varEjem= 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = varEjem * result + edad;
        result = varEjem * result + ((dni == null) ? 0 : dni.hashCode());
        result = varEjem * result + ((nombre == null) ? 0 : nombre.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
}
```

> Método `equals()`

1. El método `equals()` toma un objeto `obj` como argumento y lo compara con la instancia actual de la clase `Cliente`. Comprueba si ambos objetos son la misma instancia (si tienen la
   misma referencia en memoria), utilizando la palabra clave `this`. Si
   son la misma instancia, devuelve `true`.
2. Comprueba si el objeto es nulo `(obj == null)` y, si es así, devuelve
   `false`.
3. Comprueba si ambos objetos son de la misma clase `(getClass() != obj.getClass())` y, si no lo son, devuelve `false`. (esto evita que se produzcan excepciones de tipo `ClassCastException` al intentar castear el objeto a `Cliente`).
4. Se realiza una conversión de `obj` a `Cliente` mediante el `cast(Cliente)` `obj`. Si el objeto es una instancia de `Cliente`, el casting tendrá éxito; de lo contrario, se lanzará una excepción de tipo `ClassCastException`.
5. Finalmente, se comparan los atributos dni, edad y nombre de la instancia actual de `Cliente` y del objeto `Cliente` que se ha pasado como argumento. Si ambos son iguales, el método devuelve `true`. Si no lo son, devuelve `false`.

> Método `hashCode()`

Devuelve un valor entero que se basa en los atributos de la instancia actual de la clase `Cliente`.

1. Se crea una variable entera llamada `varEjem` y le asigna el valor 31. Esta variable se utiliza para generar el valor hash final.
2. Se crea una variable entera llamada `result` y se le asigna el valor 1. Se usa esta variable para acumular los valores hash de los atributos de la instancia actual de `Cliente`.
3. Se multiplica el valor hash actual de `result` por el valor de `varEjem` y se le suma el valor hash del atributo edad utilizando el operador `+=`. Esto significa que el valor hash de la edad contribuirá al valor hash final de la instancia actual de Cliente.
4. Se multiplica el valor hash actual de `result` por el valor de `varEjem` y se le suma el valor hash del atributo nombre y dni utilizando el método `hashCode()` de la clase `String`. Si el atributo nombre o dni es nulo, se utiliza el valor 0 en su lugar.
5. Finalmente, el método devuelve el valor `hash` acumulado en la variable `result`.

En resumen el método `equals()` se utiliza para comparar dos objetos de la clase Cliente y determinar si son iguales en función de sus atributos y el método `hashCode()` se utiliza para generar un valor hash único para la instancia actual de la clase Cliente, que se basa en los valores de sus atributos dni, edad y nombre.

Comment: Muchas gracias, no sabía lo del método hashCode(), pensaba que al definir una colección como Set ya no podía haber duplicados. Lo tengo en cuenta.